# How to view library functions of c++ in visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Without downloading or accessing the internet, is there a way to view all library functions in visual studio? Let's say i forgot what the sort() function is named as, but i know it is in "algorithm.h"; Without opening the header file itself, does visual studio offer a cleaner way of viewing those functions?

Comment: You mean like the built-in help?

Comment: There is a window called "Help Viewer" which you can use. I don't know if they offer C++ documentation. They only offer Visual C++, which isn't exactly C++

Comment: Back in the good old days, you could install MSDN locally. It might be worth finding an old distribution of it if you need access to offline documentation.